# Moving data into a new table and returning the Identity to update the original table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with several columns, one of which contains varbinay data.  I want to be able to move this varbinary data to a separate table, get the Identity for each new row added, then update my original table with this identity.  Any ideas of the best way to accomplish this?

Jon

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time move, I wouldn't want to write complicated sproc. I would move the varbinary data as well as the primary key to the new table. The new table will have its own primary key as well the foreign key to the old table. Once the move is done, you can use the primary/foreign key to update the old table (assuming you have created a column) with the primary key of the new table. Then you can remove the foreign key from the new table.